# How do I multiply output by user input in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm looking for a user to give a number, and my output be stars/astericks as many times as they entered.

Here is my code. My aim was to receive a number of inputs from user, then give them back their input. All of this works 90% as intended.

```
listSize = input("Hello, please enter an integer "
                     "value the size of your list: ")
l = list()
 
for i in range(int(listSize)):
    oneToTen = int(input("Please enter an integer "
                         "value between 1 and 10 (inclusive): "))
    if oneToTen <= 0:
        oneToTen = 1
    elif oneToTen > 10:
        oneToTen = 10
    else:
        oneToTen = oneToTen
  
    l.append(oneToTen)
 
for i in range(0, len(l)):
    print (l[i])
```

For the last 10% I intend for the user to give a star rating to a movie. So instead of the output being their numerical inputs, I want the output to be a number of asterisks based on their input. This part works, but I don't know how to combine my two sets of code.

```
star = "*"
stars = oneToTen * star
print(stars)
```

Example: If a user inputs 4, currently the output is "4". Instead, I would like the output to be "****"

Thank you!

Comment: `print(l[i] * "*")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace the last print message with the star code.

```
listSize = input("Hello, please enter an integer "
                     "value the size of your list: ")
l = list()

for i in range(int(listSize)):
    oneToTen = int(input("Please enter an integer "
                         "value between 1 and 10 (inclusive): "))
    if oneToTen <= 0:
        oneToTen = 1
    elif oneToTen > 10:
        oneToTen = 10
    else:
        oneToTen = oneToTen

    l.append(oneToTen)


star = "*"
for i in range(0, len(l)):
   stars = l[i] * star
   print(stars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```py
    listSize = input("Hello, please enter an integer "
                     "value the size of your list: ")
    data = list()

    for i in range(int(listSize)):
        oneToTen = int(input("Please enter an integer "
                             "value between 1 and 10 (inclusive): "))
        if oneToTen <= 0:
            oneToTen = 1
        elif oneToTen > 10:
            oneToTen = 10

        data.append(oneToTen)

    for i in data:
        star = "*"
        stars = i * star
        print(stars)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you are thinking about checking what the user enters. Never trust user input. What happens if the user doesn't enter a number?

> Please enter an integer value between 1 and 10 (inclusive): hello world

this will give a `ValueError`. You can handle that like this:

```
try:
    starCount = int(input("Hello, please enter an integer, from 1 to 10: "))
except ValueError:
    print("You didn't enter a number")
    exit(1)
```

This way we will only get past that point if the input is an integer. That means it's safe to do some math with the inputted value, and there is a quick way to restrict the range of an integer in this case:

```
starCount = starCount % 11
```

This will take the remainder of the input value divided by 11, which will always be between 0 and 10, inclusive.

Python will let you multiply a string by an integer, so this is valid:

```
print("*" * starCount)
```

Finally, it can all be put together into a function:

```
def f():
    try:
        starCount = int(input("Hello, please enter an integer, from 1 to 10: "))
        starCount = starCount % 11
        print("*" * starCount)
    except ValueError:
        print("You didn't enter a number")
```

> >>> f()
>
> Hello, please enter an integer, from 1 to 10: 10
>
> **********
>
> >>> f()
>
> Hello, please enter an integer, from 1 to 10: a
>
> You didn't enter a number